# how to pass parameters in groovy script using some java code

Tags: java, groovy, automation, soapui

I want to automate my test. for this I have written a script in groovy in soapui. Now I am calling that script using java code. but I want to pass parameters given by user.  I saw some interface like soapui script or script engine. would it help? I know I should not ask without trying anything but I don't know how to begin. please help me out

Comment: By the way, is [this](https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Open-Source/how-to-pass-parameters-in-groovy-script-using-some-java-code/m-p/119986#M20704) question yours?

Comment: Yes,sir,is this wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume there is a script in src/test/groovy/com/ka/script.groovy and a test in src/test/java/com/ka/MyScriptTest.java

script.groovy

```
println "Hello ${name}"
name
```

MyScriptTest.java

```
package com.ka;

import groovy.lang.Binding;
import groovy.lang.GroovyShell;
import groovy.lang.Script;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.io.*;

public class MyScriptTest {

    @Test
    public void executeScript() {
        Binding binding = new Binding();
        binding.setVariable("name", "anonymous");

        GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell(binding);
        Script script = shell.parse(getScript("./src/test/groovy/com/ka/script.groovy"));

        ByteArrayOutputStream scriptOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        PrintStream newOut = new PrintStream(scriptOutput);
        PrintStream oldOut = System.out;

        try {
            System.setOut(newOut);
            Object result = script.run();
            System.out.println("result = " + result);
        } finally {
            System.setOut(oldOut);
        }

        System.out.println("script output = " + scriptOutput.toString());
    }

    private InputStreamReader getScript(String scriptPath) {
        try {
            return new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(scriptPath));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Here the test passes the name variable's value to the script. It's what you need as I undestand.